# Having Identity column in sql table increases the performace with query used for that table

Tags: sql

I have created a table without any indexes and identity columns. I don't have any necessity for the identity column. If I add the identity column will it increase the execution of query(SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE) used with that table.

Comment: Are you using `Microsoft SQL Server`?

Comment: Having no indexes at all actually isn't the best strategy - see [Kim Tripp's blog post](http://sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/The-Clustered-Index-Debate-Continues.aspx) on why having a **good** clustering index actually speeds up all operations on that table (compared to having no indices at all)

Comment: @marc_s: with all due respect to Kimberly, this is only true for single-value inserts into a small-sized table. For block inserts into a really large table (and that's what usually done in log tables where you should insert as fast as possible no matter what), the heap tables are better.

Comment: @quassnoi: it's not like the OP is mentioning anything in that respect - the vast majority of INSERTs are really just a small row / a few fields

Comment: @marc_s: sure, that's why the vast majority of tables are clustered. I wasn't talking of them, my point was that there are situations, possibly not related to @op's one, where a heap table is better.

Answer (score 2):

`IDENTITY` has nothing to do with the indexes or performance, it just allows you not to worry about the values of the surrogate keys.

It's a part of the table's metadata and not inferred from the actual values.

Answer (score 2):

If you added an identity field as a PK you might have an increase in performance as it would create a unique index automatically.  However the increase in performance is from the indexing not the fact that it is an identity. You could simliarly increate performance by adding an index to whatever your current natural key is. If you have no natural, you may need to re-think the table design. **All tables should have a way to uniquely identify a row.**

Now indexes may not do much for performance if you do not have many rows in the table.

Why are you not using indexes?

Comment: There are some rare cases where uniquely identifying a row is not important and therefore only adds overhead to the table (e.g. event log). This, of course, does NOT mean you don't index (including clustering) it. Similarly, surrogate keys are [almost always] a waste of space unless you're tracking transactions, in which case the value of the surrogate key becomes part of the information about the record upon insert (meaning it's no longer actually surrogate).

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to speed up your queries, the first thing you should do is add appropriate indexes.  A primary key will have an index added automatically, but you'll have to create the rest of the indexes by hand.

It depends on your platform on how these are created.  A quick search in Google should teach you how to add these indexes to increase your performance.

Answer (score 1):

if you have many rows(100K +) you are going to need indexes for performance gains, if you have few rows then you will not feel the performance gain.

Adding identity as said before will only be another data on table and will not affect performance but you still do need to use indexes if you have many rows.